# SQL procedure to select a column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tring to write a sql procedure with some select and insert statements. But I am getting some errors. I am not able to figure out what the problem is. Kindly help me.

Following is the error I am getting:

> Error(15,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   Error(15,22): PLS-00201: identifier 'PROJECT_ID' must be declared

Code:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE UPDATION 
(
 NO_IN IN VARCHAR2  
) IS 
poject_id defects.reference_id%type;

BEGIN
Select REFERENCE_ID INTO poject_id from DEFECTS where ID=NO_IN;
dbms_output.put_line(project_id);

if poject_id is not null then
dbms_output.put_line('proj not null');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: `if poject_id is not null then` - missed letter 'R'

Answer (score 4):

You had syntax error on the project_id declaration.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE UPDATION 
(
 NO_IN IN VARCHAR2  
) IS 
project_id defects.reference_id%type;

BEGIN
Select REFERENCE_ID INTO project_id from DEFECTS where ID=NO_IN;
dbms_output.put_line(project_id );

if project_id is not null then
dbms_output.put_line('proj not null');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much..It was a stupid mistake I made..Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TeenaSam Glad i helped!

Answer (score 0):

> line 6
>   **poject**_id defects.reference_id%type;
>
> project*

Comment: my bad ... didn't know there is already an answer